# Action of complex Lie group on Dolbeault cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold acted holomorphically by a complex Lie group $G$. Let $F$ be a holomorphic $G$-equivariant vector bundle over $M$.

Consider the natural representation of $G$ in (say, Dolbeault) cohomology of $F$.

**Is this representation holomorphic?**

A reference is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by ''holomorphic representation''? Does it preserve the complex structure on the vector space $H^q(M, F)$?

Comment: By the way, a theorem of Klemyatin says that if $G$ preserves a Hermitian metric on $M$, then it acts trivially on the Dolbeault cohomology of $M$, you might find it interesting: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.04075.pdf